# How can you set the order of the items in a nested array for an Active Record object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Here's the code I have:

```
def show
  @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
  @tournament.games = @tournament.games.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
  puts @tournament.games.inspect
end
```

I'm trying to sort the games in the tournament. If I do `puts @tournament.games.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)` it *returns* the games in the correct order. But I can't seem to actually change `@tournament.games`. I've tried the assignment, no assignment, `order!`, `order` without the `!`, and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You have `has_many :games` in `Tournament`, right? If so, the only way to get the games in any particular order is to say `@tournament.games.order(...)`; SQL tables are unordered sets of rows, if you want the rows in a particular order then you have to ORDER BY to get them that way.

Comment: @muistooshort I do have `has_many :games` in `tournament.rb`, yes. The issue is that when I call `@tournament.games.order(...)` (with or without assignment) it doesn't actually order the games (as `puts @tournament.games.inspect` shows). It only _returns_ the ordered games. But taking that return value and assigning it to `@tournament.games` doesn't work either.

Comment: The scope may work, but you still need pass parameters in. Alternatively, I suggest you can use `@games = @tournament.games.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)`, and call `@games` in your view. Beware of SQL injection attach if you are getting `sort_column` and `sort_direction` from the browser.

Comment: @FeifeiXiong the `@games = ...` approach works, so thank you for pointing that out. However, I would like to know why `@tournament.games = ...` _doesn't_ work, and why the just `@tournament.games.order(...)` without assignment doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @AdamZerner, there is no writer method for `@tournament.games`, when you call `@tournament.games`, it should always get the games of the tournament with default scope.

Comment: @FeifeiXiong It seems that there is a writer method: [collection=(objects)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-objects). I can't find any documentation about how that relates to ordering though. I also can't find any documentation about what `@tournament.games.order` is actually doing. Is it supposed to be changing the order of the `@tournament.games` array in place?

Comment: @AdamZerner @AdamZerner The `@torunament.games` is not a normal array, it is an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy. In my understanding, the writer method is changing the associated records, and if you call `@tournament.save`, it will save these data to the database. But this won't change the order. The default order is id asc, and u can change the default order by adding scope in has_many associations or adding default_scope to Game.

Comment: `@tournament.games` will generate a SQL: `SELECT  "games".* FROM "games" WHERE "games"."tournament_id" = @tournament.id`. `@tournament.games.order(‘id desc’)` will generate a SQL: ‘SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."user_id" = @tournament.id ORDER BY id desc`.  The order mthod in `@tournament.games.order()` is not changing the order of the @tournamet.games. It adds order to SQL. That's my understanding, I suggest you to read the official rails guide, it should have more clear explanation.